# Keep hiddenField value on postback in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postback

I have hiddenfield in `_layout` file. When user logged in I am checking a value in database. if it is true poping up a dialog box to user. if user close the dialog box I will not show the message box he loggout. so I am doing like this.

_layout

```
@Html.Hidden("BadAddressWarning","")
```

layout.js

```
    $(function () {
        if ($("#BadAddressWarning").val() == "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Address/CheckPrimaryAddressGood',
            type: "Get",
            ....
           success: function(data) {
            if (data != "") {                
            $("#dialogCheckAddress").dialog({
                  ...
            });
            $("#dialogCheckAddress").dialog("open");
            $("#dialogCheckAddress").on("dialogbeforeclose", function(event, ui) {
                   $("#BadAddressWarning").val("false");
            });
            }

            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If I do post back. I am losing `$("#BadAddressWarning").val()`. I would like retain that value.

Comment: Outside of the obligatory "there is no postback in MVC", the hidden field needs to be inside of your form tag in order for it to be part of the POST collection.  Keeping it inside of the POST collection allows you to send the value back to the new view.  From the sounds of your description, it is not wrapped inside of your form tag.  You could use javascript to copy this value into an actual hidden form field in your form on submit.  Or option 2, place that in session or a cookie when you need to hold onto the value between request.

Answer (score 1):

You're  explicitly passing an empty string as the value. Instead, do something like:

```
@Html.Hidden("BadAddressWarning", Request["BadAddressWarning"])
```

Or even simpler:

```
@Html.Hidden("BadAddressWarning")
```